# Have Grunt generate index.html for different setups

Tags: javascript, build, build-automation, gruntjs

I'm trying to use Grunt as a build tool for my webapp.

I want to have at least two setups:

**I. Development setup** - load scripts from separate files, without concatenation,

so my index.html would look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/module1.js" />
        <script src="js/module2.js" />
        <script src="js/module3.js" />
        ...
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

**II. Production setup** - load my scripts minified & concatenated in one file,

with index.html accordingly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/MyApp-all.min.js" />
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The question is, *how can I make grunt make these index.html's depending on the configuration when I run `grunt dev` or `grunt prod`?*

Or maybe I'm digging in the wrong direction and it would be easier to always generate `MyApp-all.min.js` but put inside it either all my scripts (concatenated) or a loader script that asynchronously loads those scripts from separate files?

How do you do it, guys?

Comment: Try Yeoman tool, which includes a 'usemin' task which does what you one. In addition, Yeamon generators includes a lot of "good practices" easy to learn that are hard to learn when using a new tool.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've come up with my own solution. Not polished yet but I think I'm going to move in that direction.

In essense, I'm using [grunt.template.process()](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/api_template.md) to generate my `index.html` from a template that analyzes current configuration and produces either a list of my original source files or links to a single file with minified code. The below example is for js files but the same approach can be extended to css and any other possible text files.

**`grunt.js`:**

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var   // js files
        jsFiles = [
              'src/module1.js',
              'src/module2.js',
              'src/module3.js',
              'src/awesome.js'
            ];

    // Import custom tasks (see index task below)
    grunt.loadTasks( "build/tasks" );

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: '<json:package.json>',
      meta: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
          '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */'
      },

      jsFiles: jsFiles,

      // file name for concatenated js
      concatJsFile: '<%= pkg.name %>-all.js',

      // file name for concatenated & minified js
      concatJsMinFile: '<%= pkg.name %>-all.min.js',

      concat: {
        dist: {
            src: ['<banner:meta.banner>'].concat(jsFiles),
            dest: 'dist/<%= concatJsFile %>'
        }
      },
      min: {
        dist: {
        src: ['<banner:meta.banner>', '<config:concat.dist.dest>'],
        dest: 'dist/<%= concatJsMinFile %>'
        }
      },
      lint: {
        files: ['grunt.js'].concat(jsFiles)
      },
      // options for index.html builder task
      index: {
        src: 'index.tmpl',  // source template file
        dest: 'index.html'  // destination file (usually index.html)
      }
    });


    // Development setup
    grunt.registerTask('dev', 'Development build', function() {
        // set some global flags that all tasks can access
        grunt.config('isDebug', true);
        grunt.config('isConcat', false);
        grunt.config('isMin', false);

        // run tasks
        grunt.task.run('lint index');
    });

    // Production setup
    grunt.registerTask('prod', 'Production build', function() {
        // set some global flags that all tasks can access
        grunt.config('isDebug', false);
        grunt.config('isConcat', true);
        grunt.config('isMin', true);

        // run tasks
        grunt.task.run('lint concat min index');
    });

    // Default task
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'dev');
};
```

**`index.js (the index task)`:**

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    grunt.registerTask( "index", "Generate index.html depending on configuration", function() {
        var conf = grunt.config('index'),
            tmpl = grunt.file.read(conf.src);

        grunt.file.write(conf.dest, grunt.template.process(tmpl));

        grunt.log.writeln('Generated \'' + conf.dest + '\' from \'' + conf.src + '\'');
    });
}
```

Finally, **`index.tmpl`**, with generation logic baked in:

```
<doctype html>
<head>
<%
    var jsFiles = grunt.config('jsFiles'),
        isConcat = grunt.config('isConcat');

    if(isConcat) {
        print('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + grunt.config('concat.dist.dest') + '"></script>\n');
    } else {
        for(var i = 0, len = jsFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
            print('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + jsFiles[i] + '"></script>\n');
        }
    }
%>
</head>
<html>
</html>
```

---

**UPD.** Found out that [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which is based on grunt, has a built-in [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/blob/0.9.6/cli/tasks/usemin.js) task that integrates with Yeoman's build system. It generates a production version of index.html from information in development version of index.html as well as other environment settings. A bit sophisticated but interesting to look at.

Comment: [**grunt-template**](http://git.io/grunt-template) is a very lightweight wrapper around `grunt.template.process()` (which is what you’re using here) that would make this even easier. You could do the same thing using [grunt-template](http://git.io/grunt-template) by simply passing in a different `data` object for dev/prod.

Answer (score 161):

I recently discovered these Grunt `v0.4.0` compatible tasks:

- [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-preprocess/)

> Grunt task around preprocess npm module.

- [grunt-env](https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-env/)

> Grunt task to automate environment configuration for future tasks.

Below are snippets from my `Gruntfile.js`.

ENV setup:

```
env : {
    
    options : {
        
        /* Shared Options Hash */
        //globalOption : 'foo'
        
    },
    
    dev: {
        
        NODE_ENV : 'DEVELOPMENT'
        
    },
    
    prod : {
        
        NODE_ENV : 'PRODUCTION'
        
    }
    
},
```

Preprocess:

```
preprocess : {
    
    dev : {
        
        src : './src/tmpl/index.html',
        dest : './dev/index.html'
        
    },
    
    prod : {
        
        src : './src/tmpl/index.html',
        dest : '../<%= pkg.version %>/<%= now %>/<%= ver %>/index.html',
        options : {
            
            context : {
                name : '<%= pkg.name %>',
                version : '<%= pkg.version %>',
                now : '<%= now %>',
                ver : '<%= ver %>'
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

grunt.registerTask('dev', ['jshint', 'env:dev', 'clean:dev', 'preprocess:dev']);

grunt.registerTask('prod', ['jshint', 'env:prod', 'clean:prod', 'uglify:prod', 'cssmin:prod', 'copy:prod', 'preprocess:prod']);
```

And in the `/src/tmpl/index.html` template file (for example):

```
<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'DEVELOPMENT' -->
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/foo1.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/foo2.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/jquery.blah.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/jquery.billy.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/js/jquery.jenkins.js"></script>
    
<!-- @endif -->

<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'PRODUCTION' -->
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="http://cdn.foo.com/<!-- @echo name -->/<!-- @echo version -->/<!-- @echo now -->/<!-- @echo ver -->/js/<!-- @echo name -->.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- @endif -->
```

I'm sure my setup is different than most people, and the usefulness of the above will depend on your situation. For me, while it's an awesome bit of code, the Yeoman [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) is a more robust than I personally need.

**NOTE:** I *just* discovered the above listed tasks today, so I might be missing a feature and/or my process may change down the road. For now, I'm loving the simplicity **and** features that [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-preprocess/) and [grunt-env](https://github.com/onehealth/grunt-env/) have to offer. :)

---

I'm not sure if it will be of any help to anyone, but I've created [this demo repository on GitHub](https://github.com/mhulse/grunt-html-boiler) that shows a complete (and more complex setup) using the technique(s) I've outlined above.

Comment: @sthomps Glad it helped! Ever since I discovered those tasks, I've been lovin' the workflow. FYI, I've made one slight change to the process ... Instead of passing several context variables to my html templates, I opted to pass one var `path : '/<%= pkg.name %>/dist/<%= pkg.version %>/<%= now %>/<%= ver %>'` which concats all vars (that's my build path). On my template I'll have: `<script src="http://cdn.foo.com<!-- @echo path -->/js/bulldog.min.js"></script>`. Anyway, I'm happy that I was able to save you some time! :D

Comment: You could do the same thing using only [grunt-template](http://git.io/grunt-template), by simply passing in a different `data` object for dev/prod.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Thanks for the tip! I'm looking forward to checking out our code. At the time of my original posting, I don't think there were many grunt `0.4.x` plugins that did this type of thing. It's nice to know there are more options out there. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @DarrellO'Donnell Thanks! Glad it helped. FYI, not sure if it will be of any help, but I've updated my answer to include a link to a demo repository with a working example of the technique(s) I mention.

Comment: Thanks. preprocess worked better for me. usemin is way to convoluted

Comment: I know someone below mentioned that it would be a pain to maintain the script tags, but in my case this is a perfect solution. I am using requirejs, so there are only ever two possibilities for included script tags: either the dev environment's data-main="main.js" script tag, or a script tag linking to a concatenated/minified bundle.js. Point being this is a perfect solution if you're using a script loader, which you should be for your own sake.

Answer (score 15):

I dislike the solutions here (including [the one I previously gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18319872/61624)) and here's why:

- The problem with [the highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14970339/61624) is that you have to manually sync the list of script tags when you add/rename/delete a JS file.
- The problem with [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424966/61624) is that your list of JS files can't have pattern matching.  This means you've got to update it by hand in the Gruntfile.

I've figured out how to solve both of these issues.  I've set up my grunt task so that every time a file is added or deleted, the script tags automatically get generated to reflect that.  This way, **you don't need to modify your html file or your grunt file** when you add/remove/rename your JS files.

To summarize how that works, I have a html template with a variable for the script tags.  I use https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace to populate that variable.  In dev mode, that variable comes from a globbing pattern of all my JS files.  The watch task recalculates this value when a JS file is added or removed.

Now, to get different results in dev or prod mode, you simply populate that variable with a different value.  Here's some code:

```
var jsSrcFileArray = [
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/Constants.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/Random.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/Vector.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/scripts.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/StatsData.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/js/Dialog.js',
    'src/main/scripts/app/**/*.js',
    '!src/main/scripts/app/js/AuditingReport.js'
];

var jsScriptTags = function (srcPattern, destPath) {
    if (srcPattern === undefined) {
        throw new Error("srcPattern undefined");
    }
    if (destPath === undefined) {
        throw new Error("destPath undefined");
    }
    return grunt.util._.reduce(
        grunt.file.expandMapping(srcPattern, destPath, {
            filter: 'isFile',
            flatten: true,
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.'
        }),
        function (sum, file) {
            return sum + '\n<script src="' + file.dest + '" type="text/javascript"></script>';
        },
        ''
    );
};

...

grunt.initConfig({

    includereplace: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                globals: {
                    scriptsTags: '<%= jsScriptTags(jsSrcFileArray, "../../main/scripts/app/js")%>'
                }
            },
            src: [
                'src/**/html-template.html'
            ],
            dest: 'src/main/generated/',
            flatten: true,
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
        },
        prod: {
            options: {
                globals: {
                    scriptsTags: '<script src="app.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'
                }
            },
            src: [
                'src/**/html-template.html'
            ],
            dest: 'src/main/generatedprod/',
            flatten: true,
            cwd: '.',
            expand: true
        }

...

    jsScriptTags: jsScriptTags
```

`jsSrcFileArray` is your typical grunt file-globbing pattern.  `jsScriptTags` takes the `jsSrcFileArray` and concatenates them together with `script` tags on both sides.  `destPath` is the prefix I want on each file.

And here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Example</title>

</head>

<body>    
@@scriptsTags
</body>
</html>
```

Now, as you can see in the config, I generate the value of that variable as a hard coded `script` tag when it's run in `prod` mode.  In dev mode, this variable will expand to a value like this:

```
<script src="../../main/scripts/app/js/Constants.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../main/scripts/app/js/Random.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../main/scripts/app/js/Vector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../main/scripts/app/js/StatsData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../main/scripts/app/js/Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

PS: This is a crazy amount of code for something I'd want to do in every client-side JS app.  I hope someone can turn this into a reusable plugin.  Maybe I will some day.

Comment: Sounds promising. Any chance you could share some snippets?

Comment: `I've set up my grunt task so that every time a file is added or deleted, the script tags automatically get generated to reflect that` How did you do that?

Comment: Another question: Do you know of a way to just delete blocks of HTML `<script>` tags?

Comment: @Imray not off the top of my head.  You mean without any form of templating (e.g., grunt-include-replace)?  The first thought that pops into my head would be xslt.  Probably not a good solution, though.

Comment: This answer is spot on, though I personally removed `destPath` from `jsScriptTags` and swapped `grunt.file.expandMapping` with `grunt.file.expand` as the files I wanted were already in the correct places. This simplified things a lot. Thank you @DanielKaplan, you've saved me a huge amount time :)

Comment: @DanielM glad it helped.  I still want to turn this into a plug-in some day.

Answer (score 14):

I have been asking myself the same question for a while, and I think this grunt plugin could be configured to do what you want: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-targethtml. It implements conditional html tags, that depend on the grunt target.

Comment: I have seen this plugin but I don't like the idea of manually specifying all the files (and actually having any logic) in my index.html because I already have a list of source js/css files in my grunt configuration and don't want to repeat myself. Bottom line is - **it's not in index.html where you should decide what files to include**

Comment: +1 for grunt-targethtml. Although it is a bit ugly to add if statements to "decide" in your index.html which assets to load. Still, it does make sense. This is the place you will normally look to include resources in your project. Also, following up on this led me to check out grunt-contrib. It has some great stuff in it.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a more simple, straight forward solution so I combined the answer from this question:

[How to place if else block in gruntfile.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010621/how-to-place-if-else-block-in-gruntfile-js)

and came up with following simple steps:

1. Keep two versions of your index files as you listed and name them index-development.html and index-prodoction.html.
2. Use the following logic in your Gruntfile.js's concat/copy block for your index.html file:

   ```
   concat: {
       index: {
           src : [ (function() {
               if (grunt.option('Release')) {
                 return 'views/index-production.html';
               } else {
                 return 'views/index-development.html';
               }
             }()) ],
          dest: '<%= distdir %>/index.html',
          ...
       },
       ...
   },
   ```
3. run 'grunt --Release' to choose the index-production.html  file and leave off the flag to have the development version.

No new plugins to add  or configure and no new grunt tasks.

Comment: The only downside here is there are two index.html files to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

This grunt task named [scriptlinker](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-scriptlinker) looks like an easy way to add the scripts in dev mode.  You could probably run a concat task first and then point it to your concatenated file in prod mode.

Comment: +1. The documentation is confusing and some stuff (appRoot, relative) doesn't always work as intended, but still: helpful tool.

Comment: @hashchange I don't use this tool.  I ended up using https://github.com/alanshaw/grunt-include-replace instead.  I have a variable in my html file represent the script tags.  Then I populate that variable with a String of the html I want.  In dev mode, this variable is a list of the scripts.  In prod mode this variable is the concatenated, minified version.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to grunt-include-replace. (I actually needed a tool for adding all spec files in a directory to a Mocha index.html file. Scriptlinker is fine for that.)

Comment: @hashchange you're right about the documentation sucking.  How do you tell it *where* to put the script tiles in your html file?

Comment: You define an HTML comment. Have a look at [this file](http://goo.gl/dwO6qx). Insertions happen at `<!--SINON COMPONENT SCRIPTS-->` and `<!--SPEC SCRIPTS-->`. And [here](http://goo.gl/O2QE7I) is the Grunt task that does it (an actual working one, as opposed to the stuff in the docs). Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 5):

[grunt-dom-munger](https://github.com/cgross/grunt-dom-munger) reads and manipulates HTML with CSS selectors. Ex. read  tags from your html. Remove nodes, add nodes, and more.

You can use grunt-dom-munger to read all your JS files that are linked by your index.html, uglify them and then use grunt-dom-munger again to modify your index.html to only link the minified JS

Answer (score 5):

I found a grunt plugin called grunt-dev-prod-switch. All it does is comment out certain blocks it looks for based on an --env option you pass to grunt (although it limits you to dev, prod, and test).

Once you set it up as it explains [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-dev-prod-switch), you can run for example:

`grunt serve --env=dev`, and all it does is comment out the blocks which are wrapped by

```
    <!-- env:test/prod -->
    your code here
    <!-- env:test/prod:end -->
```

and it will uncomment out blocks which are wrapped by

```
    <!-- env:dev -->
    your code here
    <!-- env:dev:end -->
```

It also works on javascript, I use it for setting up the right IP address to connect to for my backend API. The blocks just change to

```
    /* env:dev */
    your code here
    /* env:dev:end */
```

In your case, it would be as simple as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- env:dev -->
        <script src="js/module1.js" />
        <script src="js/module2.js" />
        <script src="js/module3.js" />
        ...
        <!-- env:dev:end -->
        <!-- env:prod -->
        <script src="js/MyApp-all.min.js" />
        ...
        <!-- env:prod:end -->
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

grunt-bake is a fantastic grunt script that would work great here. I use it in my JQM auto build script.

https://github.com/imaginethepoet/autojqmphonegap

Take a look at my grunt.coffee file:

```
bake:
    resources: 
      files: "index.html":"resources/custom/components/base.html"
```

This looks at all the files in base.html and sucks them in to create index.html works fantastic for multipage apps (phonegap). This allows for easier development as all devs are not working on one long single page app (preventing lots of conflict checkins). Instead you can break up the pages and work on smaller chunks of code and compile to the full page using a watch command.

Bake reads the template from base.html and injects the component html pages on watch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

jQuery Mobile Demos

app.initialize();

```
<body>
    <!--(bake /resources/custom/components/page1.html)-->
    <!--(bake /resources/custom/components/page2.html)-->
    <!--(bake /resources/custom/components/page3.html)-->
</body>
```

You can take this a step further and add injections in your pages for "menus" "popups" etc so you can really break pages into smaller manageable components.

Comment: Maybe you can enhance your answer with a code demo that uses grunt-bake?

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of wiredep https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep and usemin https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin in order to have grunt take care of these tasks. Wiredep will add your dependencies one script file at a time, and usemin will concatenate them all into a single file for production. This can then be accomplished with just some html comments. For instance, my bower packages are automatically included and added to the html when I run `bower install && grunt bowerInstall`:

```
<!-- build:js /scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not for noobs!

Use Jade templating ... passing variables to a Jade template is a bog standard use case

I am using grunt (grunt-contrib-jade) but you don't have to use grunt. Just use the standard npm jade module.

If using grunt then your gruntfile would like something like ...

```
jade: {
    options: {
      // TODO - Define options here
    },
    dev: {
      options: {
        data: {
          pageTitle: '<%= grunt.file.name %>',
          homePage: '/app',
          liveReloadServer: liveReloadServer,
          cssGruntClassesForHtmlHead: 'grunt-' + '<%= grunt.task.current.target %>'
        },
        pretty: true
      },
      files: [
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: "src/app",
          src: ["index.jade", "404.jade"],
          dest: "lib/app",
          ext: ".html"
        },
        {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          cwd: "src/app",
          src: ["directives/partials/*.jade"],
          dest: "lib/app/directives/partials",
          ext: ".html"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

We can now easily access the data passed by grunt in the Jade template.

Much like the approach used by Modernizr, I set a CSS class on the HTML tag according to the value of the variable passed and can use JavaScript logic from there based on whether the CSS class is present or not.

This is great if using Angular since you can do ng-if's to include elements in the page based on whether the class is present.

For example, I might include a script if the class is present ...

(For example, I might include the live reload script in dev but not in production)

```
<script ng-if="controller.isClassPresent()" src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml). It allows definition of multiple "targets" for builds. Comments are used to conditionally include or exclude material from the HTML:

```
<!-- build:js:production js/app.js -->
...
<!-- /build -->
```

becomes

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

It even purports to do nifty stuff like this (see [the README](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml/blob/master/README.md)):

```
<!-- build:[class]:dist production -->
<html class="debug_mode">
<!-- /build -->

<!-- class is changed to 'production' only when the 'dist' build is executed -->
<html class="production">
```