# Minify HTML/CSS/Javascript and replace URLs with link to Amazon S3 files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deployment, amazon-s3, minify

I have created a web app in AngularJS with a Node.js backend. I'm planning to deploy the backend to EC2 and the static files: Javascript, HTML and CSS to S3. I am using Grunt to automate tasks.

My problem is as follows. In my index.html file I have a list of script tags including a bunch of JS files, however, when these files are concatenated and minified, how do these script tags get replaced by the one (or two) script tag pointing to the minified file? Do people normally do this manually, write a script or are there any tools that can do this?

What if I want to upload these static files to S3. I have seen the S3 Grunt plugin, but how do the links to the static files get replaced in the HTML and everywhere the files are needed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups  sounds like you need to use pre-process

Comment: Yeah that thread cleared everything up. Thank you!