# Strategy to use grunt-processhtml in development

Tags: gruntjs

How should one use `grunt-processhtml` in the development environment?

For example, in `index.html`, I'll do something like load partials for angular when this is built:

```
<!-- build:include:dist views/template-main.html -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/template-main.html"> -->

</script>
<!-- /build -->
```

But I only want that to happen in the built environment, not the environment the development environment (`app/`) that's served by `grunt serve`?

Or, for a more common example,

```
<!-- @if NODE_ENV='production' -->
<script src=" production script "></script>
<!-- @endif -->
<!-- @if NODE_ENV='dev' -->
<script src=" sandbox script "></script>
<!-- @endif -->
```

How do I get only the sandbox script to be served in the development environment (`app/`) served by `grunt serve`

Should I be performing a `grunt build` every time and instead of `grunt`/`node` serving the contents of `app/`, somehow change it to serve a development build (i.e. `dist/`)

Or should I be writing these `grint-processhtml` directives (or any pre-processor) in another file, e.g. `pre.index.html` and have it built to `index.html`?

Otherwise, if `grunt-processhtml` is run, it removes the directives, if it's not, the browser obviously ignores the `grunt-processhtml` directives and loads both scripts.

(This is for a AngularJS project scaffolded by Yeoman, but is a general grunt-processhtml question)

Answer (score 1):

I think I misunderstood how to use grunt.

I suspect it would be best to add different build targets, e.g. `dev`, `production`, etc, and not just use `app/` and `dist`.

This involves setting up different built targets, setting different targets to be served.

A good explanation: [Have Grunt generate index.html for different setups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups)