# Managing JavaScript config files for different build environments (like QA, UAT, Production)

Tags: javascript, build-process, single-page-application, release-management

So you are building a stand alone Single Page Application in JavaScript that is served statically. It connects to an API.

Your application has a JSON object in its `main.js` like this:

```
var config = {
 apiPath: 'http://dev.api.example.com',
 appTitle: 'hello'
};
```

You use Grunt to create a release build, this transpiles all your SASS, ES6, AMD Modules etc code into one or two JavaScript files, along with this config object.

Your production API url is `http://api.example.com` and when you do a release build, you want just this value in the config to change. (Maybe you would want to change other config parameters too). You have a release config

```
var config = {
 apiPath: 'http://api.example.com'
};
```

How can a JavaScript config file be altered depending on different types of release environments during a build. Notice that I want to merge the release config into the default, *not* maintain totally seperate files with all the settings. While there are grunt plugins for setting a build mode, I've not found any that have the ability to update config files, only hacks that change which file is pointed to.

ASP.NET has `web.config` transforms that do exactly this, any property in the release transform for example, will overwrite the 'default' config on packaging. Does such a workflow exist using grunt or something?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a straightforward question to me.

Comment: Would something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-environment help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved the question myself by using a combination of environment variables and an amazing Node  called [Confidence](https://github.com/hapijs/confidence) which where you place all your different envs config settings in a single file, and they are resolved to a single configuration based on filters (such as an environment variable) - these can then be injected into the build process using tools like WebPack.