# How does webpack rewrite HTML pages to account for automated components processing?

Tags: html, webpack, workflow

I am learning front-end development and currently try to understand how to use automatisation systems such as `gulp`, `grunt` or `webpack`. I currently picked `webpack` and the question is targeted to that system.

I understand its general use and built configurations to automate operations such as the compilation of `.less` files or minification CSS files.

The point which escapes me is that the **development** version of (as an example) an HTML file should differ from the **production** version. Specifically, my development file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="onestyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="anotherstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrapmaybe.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello World
  <script src="somelibrary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="myown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

while the production version is rather

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="allcssminified.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello World
  <script src="alljsminified.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

where `allcssminified.min.css` and `alljsminified.min.js` are generated from the the various components of the development file, transformed though the relevant `webpack` mechanism into a compressed version.

There should however be one HTML file, common to development and production contexts, adapted depending on the context (dev or prod).

**How should this be approached with `webpack`?**

- Through some kind of HTML templating where an `if-then-else` condition would include the right section?
- Or should the whole `<link>` or `<script>` includes sections be somehow generated and included by `webpack` (which to me looks like a templating approach as well, though the decision is made by `webpack`?
- Or should there just be one include, and the components of this include would be defined in the `webpack` configuration file (in that case I always get the minified version, which is possibly not optimal for debugging)

Note: there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401998/have-grunt-generate-index-html-for-different-setups) for `grunt` back in 2012-2014 but the solutions listed there are not relevant to `webpack` and, subjectively, not very aesthetical.

Answer (score 0):

CSS: I would use one main. css file (styles.css) in your application. Then @import all of the other .less or .scss files into styles.css.  These will be compiled by WebPack assuming you are using the proper CSS loaders (style-loader, css-loader, less-loader).

JS: Define them in your entry config like so:

```
entry: ['./path/to/somelibrary.js', './path/to/myown.js']
```

They will get combined as well into one file.